# How to specify SoapHeader to Client Consumed Webservice in C#

Tags: wcf, web-services

Currently working on project and I need to consume a java web service whose document specifies that I must enter the username and password in the soap header.

Please I need help on this.

I'm consuming the webservice from .NET

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [message contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) to define your messages (headers and body), or another option would be to use [WCF behaviors to inject SOAP headers](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx) into your outgoing messages.

Comment: Nope , i was actually consuming the web service.

Comment: @AdeyinkaOluwaseunDoyin: well, even then - both approaches should work for you. You can either define a suitable message contract, or you can have a WCF behavior that inspects the message as it arrives from the web service and pull out the SOAP headers....